# $\lim_{x\to \infty}\ (\frac{x-1}{x+1})^{x+2}=? $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\ (\frac{x-1}{x+1})^{x+2}=? $$

clearly this is of the form $1^\infty$ so we can use short cut method to write...$$e^{\lim_{ x\to\infty}{(x+2)(\frac{x-1}{x+1}-1)}}$$
After this clearly the answer is $e^{-2}$ (as degree of numerator and denominator are same so only -2 remains).
I want to know other ways to solve this (may be using some standard formulae).

Comment: I would say that what you have done is the standard technique.  That, or what is mathematically the same... $L = \lim f(x) \implies \ln L = \lim \ln (f(x))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{x+2}= \lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1-\dfrac2{x+1}\right)^{x+2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\left(1-\dfrac2{x+1}\right)^\dfrac{x+1}2\right)^\dfrac{2(x+2)}{x+1}= e^{-2}.$$
Used formula
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\left(1-\dfrac1{t}\right)^t=e^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{x+2}&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)^{x+2}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)^{x+1}\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)^{x+1}\,\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)\\\\
&=e^{-2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: very clean way to show the intuitive

Comment: @qbert Thank you!  Much appreciative.